# Can't get page to display full width when shrinking

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the browser, the header and navigation bar does not extend till the end of the browser. It looks like this when I shrink the browser. I want the header and the navigation bar to extend till the end of the browser.
 [image: When shrinked]

When the browser is stretched, it's alright though!  [image: When browser is expanded]

Here's my html code :

```
<body>

<div id="header">
Some text
</div>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Here's the CSS for it:

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
background:red; 
}

#header{
    margin:0;
    background: white;
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
}


#nav {
    /* margin: 0px auto;*/
     padding-left: 100px;
     background: black;
     height:54px;
}

#nav li {
     float: left;
}

#nav li a {
     color: lime;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 54px;
     margin-right: 94px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Would really appreciate it if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Eric Meyer's reset too.

Comment: make the width parameter to percent values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#header{
    margin:0;
    background: white;
    height:90px;
    min-width:960px;
    width:100%;
}
```

here you can specify the `min-width:--;`

Comment: Thank you! =) This solution is more elegant

Answer (score 2):

Update your **css of list with percentage** spacing as follows.

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
background:red; 
}

#header{
    margin:0;
    background: white;
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
}


#nav {
    /* margin: 0px auto;*/
     padding-left: 10%;
     background: black;
     height:54px;
}

#nav li {
     float: left;
    padding-right:9%;
}

#nav li a {
     color: lime;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 54px;
     text-decoration: none;
    display:block
}
```

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vYgs5/

Comment: Thank you! =) This solution was good too, but the above was slightly more elegant and concise.

Comment: But naveen's solution will not fix the width of your navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make your website Responsive instead, the @Naveen answer is so helpful but u want to keep in mind to edit a responsive css style for all devices something like:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip Leo! =) Really appreciate it!